# C# Windows forms Listview selected item

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a listview in Windows forms populated by a SQL database. i have a button to delete records when selected and it's working fine. but if there is no selected item and i click the delete button i get and error. so i add a messagebox and a condition but a always get - ***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

so how do i check if there is a selected item in the listview so it enter the If?

thanks

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool b = this.lvBrands.FocusedItem.Checked;

        if (b == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a brand .", "Brand Select Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {
            string sID = this.lvBrands.FocusedItem.Text;
            deleteBrand(sID);
            clearBrand(); 

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
if(lvBrands.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
//you have something selected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether `FocusedElement` is not null before attempting to reference it.

```
 bool b = false;
 if(this.lvBrands.FocusedItem != null)
 {
      b = this.lvBrands.FocusedItem.Checked;
 }
```

However, as @bobek pointed out if you are looking for the selected item you should be using the `SelectedItem` instead of the `FocusedItem` property. The code would be the same, just using `SelectedItem`.